# WCF and Soap 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a service that a 3rd party should hopefully consume.
The consumer is compatible with SOAP 1.1, which is why I am using basicHttpBinding for the server. When the actual request is made, something seems to go wrong with the content types expected by the server. Using basicHttpBinding I dont get why the server still expects 'application/soap+xml' which, to my knowledge, is only required by SOAP 1.2.

I've used wireshark to figure out exactly what those two were communicating about. See tcp stream and setup below.

Any help is appreciated.

**3rd party app request**

> POST / HTTP/1.1
>
> SOAPAction:
>   http://tempuri.org/ITestService/Hello
>
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> Host: shdesktop:8000
>
> Content-Length: 297
>
> Expect: 100-continue
>
> Connection: Close

**WCF Server response**

> HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the
>   message because the content type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the
>   expected type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8'.
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2010 14:03:19 GMT
>
> Connection: close

**Service configuration**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="behTestService" name="ConsoleApplication1.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="TestService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="ConsoleApplication1.ITestService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behTestService">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `basicHttpBinding` does use SOAP 1.1 - but in that case, you would have a content type of `application/soap+xml`.

Since your client is sending `text/xml` - any chance they're expecting a REST interface? This would be handled by the WCF `webHttpBinding`.

Read more about REST in WCF on the [MSDN WCF REST Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/REST) and check out the Pluralsight [screencast series on WCF REST](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/browselibrary.aspx?technology=WCF+REST) - highly recommended!

Comment: oh, SOAP 1.1 would use 'application/soap+xml'? I will test the webHttpBinding tomorrow, thank you! I know for a fact that it works when I create a simple asmx service, if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Silas: "old-style" ASP.NET webservices (ASMX) **and** WCF basicHttpBinding use SOAP 1.1 - so that should be ok, really. You need to check whether your client is sending you a SOAP request, or just trying to post an XML to your URL

Comment: I was calling http://<hostname> instead I needed to call http://<hostname>/TestService. Stupid mistake by me. Thanks for all the help though!

Answer (score 7):

Generally when we get a message / error in a web service which includes the text:

```
content type 'text/xml'
```

It means that the web server returned an error page instead of the expected xml response.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue - the definition was saying that it was soap 1.2 but expecting 1.1 as the content-type was different.

I found that if i adjusted my server configuration from:

```xml
...
<endpoint address="" .../>
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/services/fooService" />
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
...
```

To:

```xml
...
<endpoint address="fooService" .../>
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/services" />
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
...
```

The wsdl exposed it as Soap 1.1 this time.